# Pipes: open a file according to content of another

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have this code:

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Safe
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.Safe.Prelude as P
import System.IO

import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.IO as TIO
import qualified Pipes.Prelude.Text as T

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = runSafeT $
  P.withFile file1 ReadMode $ \file1Handle -> do
    file2 <- liftIO $ TIO.hGetLine file1Handle
    runEffect $
      for (P.zip (T.fromHandleLn file1Handle)
                 (T.readFileLn $ T.unpack file2))
          (\(l1,l2) -> do yield l2
                          yield l1)
      >-> T.stdoutLn
```

But it seems quite hacky, and I would like to be able to open the second file from within the pipe, from what I read in the first line of the first file.
Any idea?

Comment: I have a feeling that's probably the cleanest code you are going to get. If you don't get an answer here try [pipes mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-pipes) - and then post the answer back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are I think a number of ways of doing this without mixing `Data.Text.IO` in with `Pipes` stuff. It is basically a `zip`, as you say. The natural way of finding out the first line of the first file is just to use `next` which, in this case, gives you the first line paired with the rest of lines:

```
someFunc_ = runSafeT $ runEffect $ do 
  e <- next (T.readFileLn file1)
  case e of
    Left r              -> return r
    Right (file2, rest) -> do 
      let other = T.readFileLn (T.unpack file2)
          amalgam = for (P.zip rest other) $ \(l1,l2) -> do
            yield l2 
            yield l1
      runEffect $ amalgam >-> T.stdoutLn
```

I think an approach that tried to do more 'inside a pipeline' would end up being more complicated than it was worth. In particular, you have to deal with the case where file1 turns out to empty. `next` is basically what you use to pattern match on a pipes `Producer`, so it's a fundamental pipes operation.

So, part for part, it's basically the same as a regular Text program like this

```
 someFunc = do
    ls <- fmap T.lines TIO.readFile file1 
    case ls of
      []         -> return ()
      file2:rest -> do 
        ls' <- fmap T.lines (TIO.readFile file1) 
        forM_ (zip ls ls') $ \(t1,t2) -> do
             TIO.putStrLn t1
             TIO.putStrLn t2
```

except that it streams properly.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed `next` was the missing element here.